Weird noise warping in material nodes
Spot highlighted in pink doesn't warp, unlike the rest of noise texture and i can't figure out why

Texture im using to warp the noise doesn't show it

Nor is it visible if i just check the coordinate space itself

If i separate the X axis from it, there's a little spot visible exactly between X and Z axis

It wasn't there before i applied the rotation transform, but i can't find any reason for it to appear
Node setup:

Blend file:


It seems to happen on both sides, and both spots are in-between mirrored warping. Apparently, the noise happens to align with the UV space there.

I have managed to fix this by just plugging it into rotation, and applying some offsets



